# pure-ftpd on CentOs

Tags: centos, centos6, ftp

I'm trying to install pureftpd on CentOS6, but when I run the yum command:

`yum install pure-ftpd`

I always get `package not found`

Is there a way I can install `pure-ftpd' in Cent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the epel repository before you can install it

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

Then your yum command will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you must configure epel repo first. There is no pure-ftpd in basics centos repo. Here is link to rpm `http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/Linux/fedora-epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm`

Download it using

`wget http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/Linux/fedora-epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm`

next install with

`rpm -ivh http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/Linux/fedora-epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm`

After that you will be able to install pure-ftpd with yum.

You can always try to compile it from source but the best choice will be instalation with yum.